# cargar información de usuarios de base de datos al iniciar sesión - react-native

Tags: react-native

tengo mi AuthContext.tsx funcionando bien, puedo iniciar sesión en mi aplicación sin problemas pero al iniciar sesión no me esta cargando los datos del usuario que inicia sesión y detecte que  const `resp = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');` en mi AuthContext.tsx no esta trayendo los datos del usuario, he intentado solucionar pero no he podido.

Nota: la API de donde carga los datos esta bien ya que la utilizo en reactjs y funciona, asi que el problema esta directamente en mi AuthContext.tsx de mi app de react-native

AuthContext.tsx

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:''


}


export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

    useEffect(() =>{
        checkToken();
    }, [])

    const checkToken = async () =>{
       const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

       //No token, no autenticado
       if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
    
       //hay token
//AL INICIAR SESIÓN DESDE AQUI ES QUE SE SUPONE QUE CARGA LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO
       const resp = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');

       if(resp.status !== 200){
          return dispatch({type:'notAuthenticated'});
       }

       await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token)

       

       dispatch({
           type: 'signUp',
           payload:{
               token: resp.data.token,
              //resp.data.usuarios no me carga nada de la base de datos de mi api
               user: resp.data.usuarios
           }
       })

    }


   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
        try {

         
         
        
     await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php',
    {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(resData => {
       if(resData.message == "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.") {

      

        dispatch({
            type: 'signUp',
            payload: {
                //el token carga sin problemas
                token: resData.token,
                //AQUI NO ME TRAE LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO, APARECE UNDEFINED
                user: resData.usuarios
            }
            
        }); 
        
              
       }else{
        Alert.alert(resData.message)
       }
       
    });

  
            
           }catch (error) {

            //console.log(error.response.data)
            dispatch({type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
           }
    };


  
    const signUp = async ({name, email, password, tipo_usuario}: RegisterData) => {

        try {
            await  fetch('https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/usuarios/register.php',
    {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"email":email, "password" : password, "name" : name,  "tipo_usuario" : tipo_usuario})
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(resData => {
       if(resData.message == "Se ha registrado exitosamente.") {

        dispatch({
            type: 'signUp',
            payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios
            }
            
        });  
        
        Alert.alert(resData.message)
       }else{
        Alert.alert(resData.message)
       }
      
    
    });



          } catch (error) {
            dispatch({type: 'addError',
                       payload: error.response.data.errors[0].msg || 'Revise la información'})
          }
    };



    const logOut = async () => {
       await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
       dispatch({type:'logout'});
    };

    const removeError = () => {

     dispatch({type: 'removeError'});

    };

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signUp,
            signIn,
            logOut,
            removeError,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

AGREGO LA API

user-info.php

```js
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require __DIR__.'/classes/Database.php';
require __DIR__.'/middlewares/Auth.php';

$allHeaders = getallheaders();
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();
$auth = new Auth($conn,$allHeaders);

$returnData = [
    "success" => 0,
    "status" => 401,
    "message" => "Unauthorized"
];

if($auth->isAuth()){
    $returnData = $auth->isAuth();
}

echo json_encode($returnData);
```

Auth.php

```js
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../classes/JwtHandler.php';
class Auth extends JwtHandler{

    protected $db;
    protected $headers;
    protected $token;
    public function __construct($db,$headers) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function isAuth(){
        if(array_key_exists('Authorization',$this->headers) && !empty(trim($this->headers['Authorization']))):
            $this->token = explode(" ", trim($this->headers['Authorization']));
            if(isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))):
                
                $data = $this->_jwt_decode_data($this->token[1]);

                if(isset($data['auth']) && isset($data['data']->user_id) && $data['auth']):
                    $user = $this->fetchUser($data['data']->user_id);
                    return $user;

                else:
                    return null;

                endif; // End of isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))
                
            else:
                return null;

            endif;// End of isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))

        else:
            return null;

        endif;
    }

    protected function fetchUser($user_id){
        try{
        //ESTOS SON LOS DATOS QUE DEBERIA CARGARME EN MI SCREEN AL INICIAR SESIÓN EN REACT-NATIVE
            $fetch_user_by_id = "SELECT `name`,`email`, `tipo_usuario` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `id`=:id";
            $query_stmt = $this->db->prepare($fetch_user_by_id);
            $query_stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query_stmt->execute();

            if($query_stmt->rowCount()):
                $row = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return [
                    'success' => 1,
                    'status' => 200,
                    'user' => $row
                ];
            else:
                return null;
            endif;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```